# Regex to match words after forward slash or in between

Tags: java, regex

I have this code that needs to get words after `/` or in between this character.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,})"); // Regex:  \/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,})
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(path);
if(matcher.matches()){
   return matcher.group(0);
}
```

The regex `\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,})` works but not in Java, what could be the reason?

Comment: You must have tested it with a javascript regex engine or with sed : `/` has no special meaning in Java's regex flavour and shouldn't be escaped.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to escape the slash twice. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value of Group 1 and use `find` to get a partial match:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(path);
if(matcher.find()){
   return matcher.group(1);  // Here, use Group 1 value
}
```

`Matcher.matches` requires a full string match, only use it if your string fully matches the pattern. Else, use `Matcher.find`.

Since the value you need is *captured* into Group 1 (`([a-zA-Z0-9]*)`, the subpattern enclosed with parentheses), you need to return that part.

You needn't escape the `/` in Java regex. Also, `{0,}` functions the same way as `*` quantifier (matches zero or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern).

Also, `[a-zA-Z0-9]` can be replaced with `\p{Alnum}` to match the same range of characters (see [Java regex syntax reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). The pattern declaration will look like

```
"/(\\p{Alnum}*)"
```